# org-journal-mode new entry ignores .dir-locals.el

Tags: org-mode, directory-local-variables

I am using `org-journal-mode`. I have created `.dir-locals.el` in my `~/Documents/journal` directory and it gets correctly applied if I open a file the usual way. However, if I hit the <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> to add a new entry and the entry is in a new day, the opened buffer does not have the modifications I apply through `.dir-locals.el`.

Can I make it recognize and process `.dir-locals.el` for new day journal entry buffers?

My `.dir-locals.el`:

```
((nil
  (fill-column . 79)
  (indent-tabs-mode)
  (show-trailing-whitespace . t)
  (whitespace-style face trailing lines-tail space-before-tab indentation empty)
  (whitespace-newline . t))
 (org-journal-mode
  (typo-language . "Czech")
  (typo-mode . t)
  (ispell-local-dictionary . "czech")
  (flyspell-mode . t)
  (whitespace-action warn-read-only auto-cleanup)))
```

Comment: See more complete discussion at https://github.com/bastibe/org-journal/issues/51